# Grails remoteLink handling error codes

Tags: grails

I'm on grails 1.3.6 and I see the following behavior.

```
<g:javascript library="prototype" />
...
<g:remoteLink action="punch" id="${personInstance.id}" update="damage_${personInstance.id}" on401="alert('foo!');">
```

generates:

```
<a on401="alert('foo!');" onclick="new Ajax.Updater('damage_5','/blah/person/punch/5',{asynchronous:true,evalScripts:true});return false;" href="/blah/person/punch/5"></a>
```

"on401" isn't a supported event attribute for an anchor tag, so is this a bug in grails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On 1.3.5 for me, it just lost on401 attribute.
Looks like bug [GRAILS-7062](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-7062).